# Go type assert nil to pointer type

Tags: go

Why can't I type-assert a nil to a pointer type? What is the logic behind this?

```
package main

func main() {
    var s interface{} = nil
    var p *string = nil
    var q *string = s.(*string)
    _ = q
    _ = p
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't type assert something with no type.

> The static type (or just type) of a variable is the type given in its
>   declaration, the type provided in the new call or composite literal,
>   or the type of an element of a structured variable. **Variables of
>   interface type also have a distinct dynamic type, which is the
>   concrete type of the value assigned to the variable at run time
>   (unless the value is the predeclared identifier nil, which has no
>   type).** The dynamic type may vary during execution but values stored in
>   interface variables are always assignable to the static type of the
>   variable.

Straight from the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables) (emphasis mine)

Interfaces know the type of the underlying value. For instance if I have a interface with a `type MyType` it can't be type asserted to `*string` either. You could perhaps convert its type with some work, but type assertion and type conversion are different.

Also take a look [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)

> For an expression x of interface type and a type T, the primary
>   expression
>
> x.(T)
>
> **asserts that x is not nil** and that the value stored in x is of
>   type T. The notation x.(T)